# Does everything of a Blockchain Network rely on its underlying "Consensus Protocol"?

Tags: blockchain, consensus

I have been reading about and researching on Blockchain Technology for quite a while now, and what I can comprehend from the very primitive architecture of these "Distributed Databases" is that everything and every procedure solely hinges upon the declared "Consensus Protocol" for reaching security and anonymity.

And the reason that currently Blockchain technology doesn't have any killer application beside financial systems is partly or mainly due to incapability of current most used "Consensus Protocols".

I'm asking whether my argument is correct or not? and if it is not, where I'm mistaking?

I'm an energy activist, and I have been studying blockchain's energy applications for 3 months now, what I have came across is that either PoW or PoS are not suitable for an energy market based on blockchain, the first one is too energy intensive and the second one promotes centralization intuitively. And also money transaction is not comparable to energy transaction, because energy needs wire and some of it is simply deterred on its way. I'm wondering whether a new protocol can solve the problem???

Comment: Your question is unclear. The consensus rules are the rules by which the blockchain is chosen (in case of a fork) and validated. A blockchain sacrifices everything to achieve decentralization. If decentralization is not needed, neither is a blockchain. Money is *the* "killer app".

Comment: @ Gendarme I'm an energy activist, and I have been studying blockchain's energy applications for 3 months now, what I have came across is that either PoW or PoS are not suitable for an energy market based on blockchain, the first one is too energy intensive and the second one promotes centralization intuitively. And also money transaction is not comparable to energy transaction, because energy needs wire and some of it is simply deterred on its way. I'm wondering whether a new protocol can solve the problem???

Comment: There is no proof that a new protocol cannot solve the problem. Such a protocol is not publicly known, however. PoW is the best we have currently.